# PHP Default Parameters Overwriting Passed Values

Tags: php, parameters, parameter-passing, param

I have a function like this:

```
protected function example($param = null)
{
}
```

and when I call it like this:

```
$this->example("string");
```

or like this:
    $string = "string";
    $this->example("string");

the parameter value is still null.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest putting in a var_dump and tracing through your code to make sure it is doing what you expect it to and for sanity reasons. Make sure you're calling the right file as well.

Comment: Can you show a *full* example that shows this issue?  Are you sure you are calling *that* function?  This looks to be in a class (because of the `protected` keyword), so you'd need `$this->example("string");`.

Comment: `example()` is not the same as `$this->example()` or `$class->example()` in OOP

Comment: How are you determining that `$param` is null?

Comment: Newbi3, I am actually calling the function from inside the same class.  I have had it write the $param value to a file, and the value is always whatever I set the default to, never the value I pass in.

Comment: @amorrise: There's something *else* wrong here.  Have you just tried `var_dump($param)` to make sure that works?

Answer (score 1):

Try returning the variable.

```
protected function example($param = null)
{
    return $param;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the parameter set to NULL only assigns the variable $param to NULL when no parameter is passed.

like when you call it like this $this->example();

Otherwise $param will be set to whatever you pass it.